# Filter the below text using shell commands

Tags: shell-script, git, diff, filter

I am able to get the file difference using `git diff` command and I got it filtered like below:

> -This folder contains common database scripts.
>
> +This folder contains common database scripts.
>
> +
>
> +
>
> +
>
> +New Line added.

However I want to be able to get only the difference that is the line `New Line added.` how can I achieve that - note that here I want to delete a pair of line containing

`'+This folder contains common database scripts.'` and

`'-This folder contains common database scripts.'`
and also remove white spaces (three '+ ' lines)

Comment: How exactly do you identify what to be extracted and what to be eliminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

If `+New Line added.` is the last line of the output of `git diff`:

`git diff | tail -1 | tr -d '\n'`

If you want to get rid of `+`

`git diff | tail -1 | sed -e 's/^+//' | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Commands work really well, I do get the expected output. However I am quite skeptical about it for a more generalized dynamic case when the above given text could be different.

How can I be sure that the difference lines will always be at the end.

Comment: @harveySp what is the exact `git diff` command that you use ?

Comment: Can you please refer to [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718895/filter-response-from-git-diff-command-to-get-only-the-difference-in-shell-dy)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex;

```
echo "-This folder contains common database scripts.
+This folder contains common database scripts.
+
+
+
+New Line added" \
| grep -Pv "^[+-]$" \
| perl -p0e 's/-.*(.{9}).*\n\+.*\1.*//g'
```

Try online  http://tpcg.io/hb9xSY